# php execute twice and records twice

Tags: php, pdo

I'm having a problem regarding this script

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
require_once("./dbconf.php");
$esmaior = new ESMAIOR($DB_con);
session_start();
$aulaAssist = 'teste';
if($aulaAssist != null){
    $idProfessorA = 23;
    $idProfessorB = 24;
    $dataA = '2017-10-01';
    $dataB = '2017-10-01';
    $discA = 23;
    $discB =24;
    $anoA = '1º';
    $anoB =  '1º';
    $ret = $esmaior->newAulaAssistida($idProfessorA, $idProfessorB, $dataA, $dataB, $discA, $discB, $anoA, $anoB);
    echo json_encode($ret);
}
```

It calls this function in my main class

```
public function newAulaAssistida($idProfessorA, $idProfessorB, $dataA, $dataB, $discA, $discB, $anoA, $anoB){
    try{
        $stmt = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO aulasassistidas (dataRegistado) VALUE (NOW());");
        $result= $stmt->execute();
        if (!$result) {
            print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
            return array('status' => 'error', 'message' => Error');
        }
        else{
            return array('status' => 'success', 'message' => '0k');
        }
    }catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

So when i check my database i have always the same item twice...at the same datetime.
I have used Firefox, Chrome, IE, Edge and all of them have the same behaviour.
Can someone help me with this issue?

Thanks

Comment: It's never useful to try different browsers when you have a server-side problem but the fact that you mentioned that made me wonder : are you sure the AJAX query isn't called twice ? Watch the "Network" tab in Chrome inspector and see how many times your browser calls HTTP request to your script **EDIT** : @chris85 is right, dont use `query` if you want to call `execute` after that. Either use `prepare()` then `execute()` or `query()` alone

Comment: You realize there's a missing quote in here `Error')` and is throwing off syntax highlighting. If there is a quote for it, please edit your post.

Comment: Side note about `VALUE`. For those who think that that isn't valid and should read as `VALUES`, both are valid in MySQL. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html

Answer (score 3):

I've never actually `query`d and `execute`d but both those functions `execute` a query so you should only use one of them. The `execute` is meant to be used with prepared statements. So you could do:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO aulasassistidas (dataRegistado) VALUE (NOW());");
$result= $stmt->execute();
```

or just:

```
$result = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO aulasassistidas (dataRegistado) VALUE (NOW());");
if (!$result) {
```

Comment: *"So you could do:"* - They'd still need to execute it; you may have meant `$stmt = $this->db->query(` and remove the `execute()`. Plus, *"The execute is meant to be used with prepared statements."* you can still use that even without placeholders, oddly enough.

Comment: @Fred-ii- They have the `execute()` already in their code. My answer is suppose to read as use `prepare` in place of `query` or remove the `execute` call.

Comment: Yes I know that. I'm not sure if saw my original comment or edited, because I did edit it once.

Comment: I guess I misinterpreted your explanation then. It seems that it should be edited :-)

Comment: btw; they have a missing quote in there and [I posted a comment about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466923/php-execute-twice-and-records-twice#comment79892130_46466923). I'm not even sure if they're around or not, or have seen your answer. Might just be a bad paste.

Comment: Yeah, that's a lot better Chris :-)